# While working with older version of Dart code, getting an error in whole project

Tags: android, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

The language version must be >=2.12.0.
Try removing the language version override and migrating the code.

[image]
[image]

Looking for the solution for the above error.Illegal_language_version_override

```
//@dart=2.9
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

Error-
Illegal_language_version_override
```

Comment: This will happen if you are using Dart SDK >= 3.0 [link](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/49530). If that's your case, you need to downgrade your SDK, or to migrate the project to a newer SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Flutter and Dart with the required versions for your codebase, and update the path in system environment; this will resolve the mentioned issues.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).